# JavaScript garbage collection/memory management

Tags: javascript, memory, knockout.js

I've looked for an answer to this on MDN and the like but can't find anything concrete. I'm trying to decide which of the following would be more memory efficient, or if they'd be the same. More importantly, I'd like to know the reasoning: (bear in mind I didn't bother with any real functionality, but the idea should be the same)

I

```
// A.js
function A() {}
module.exports = A

// B.js
var A = require('./A')
function B() {}
B.prototype = Object.create(new A)

// C.js
var A = require('./A')
function C() {}
C.prototype = Object.create(new A)
```

II

```
// A.js
function A() {}
module.exports = new A

// B.js
var A = require('./A')
function B() {}
B.prototype = Object.create(A)

// C.js
var A = require('./A')
function C() {}
C.prototype = Object.create(A)
```

I know that in both cases, all three functions have unique prototypes. What isn't clear to me is whether or not the invocation of A's constructor twice in version `I` vs only once in `II` makes any difference. If there are *any* differences you know of, please outline them. If there are not, are there any benefits to one approach or the other? Or is there possibly a third way that's better than both? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I know that not using functions at all and using plain objects would render this a moot point; unfortunately, I'm using Knockout in a project and these functions become Knockout components. I'm pretty sure when I do:

```
module.exports = { viewModel: B, template: template }
```

`B` has to be a function that Knockout can instantiate. I'm sure there are other ways, but at this point, I want to refactor/improve my code, but not do a complete overhaul.

Comment: The is no difference. 'New A' is invoked twice and it only returns the reference, whether you do it just befor or after th pushing a call on to the call stack  will not effect performance or memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think from the "working on a team" perspective it might make more sense to export the function itself and let the constructor call be made by the importing file.